# Problem compiling shared library/plugin with autotools

Tags: shared-libraries, autotools

I'm very new to autotools and it looks like I have a problem with libtool - it doesn't build a shared library and makes a static one instead...

This is how my configure.ac looks like:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.67])
AC_INIT([helloworld], [1.0], [...])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])
LT_INIT

# Checks for programs.
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_PROG_LIBTOOL

# Checks for header files.
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([alloca.h inttypes.h stdint.h])

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

and Makefile.am:

```
noinst_LTLIBRARIES=helloworld.la

helloworld_la_CXXFLAGS=-w -DLINUX ...
helloworld_la_LDFLAGS=-avoid-version -module -shared -export-dynamic

# List of source files
helloworld_la_SOURCES=helloworld.cpp ...
```

Is there something wrong here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but LT_INIT is a replacement for AC_PROG_LIBTOOL, so you can remove AC_PROG_LIBTOOL from configure.ac

Comment: Why are you trying to build a shared convenience library?  Did you intend to use noinst_LTLIBRARIES instead of lib_LTLIBRARIES?

Comment: -DLINUX has several issues.  1) It belongs in helloworld_la_CPPFLAGS, since it is for the preprocessor.  2) You should not be basing your compilation on a platform, but on particular features.  3) If you ignore rule 2, you should determine the platform at configure time and not hard code it into Makefile.am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want

```
lib_LTLIBRARIES = helloworld.la
```

Using noinst instructs libtool to build a convenience library, and those
are not typically shared.

Comment: Correct, although I would like to add that it _is_ annoying that libtool decides that for you. For example, I have test programs in one project that load (shared library) test plugins. They are not automated unit tests, so they don't belong in `check_LTLIBRARIES` - but they are not meant for installing either. So `noinst_LTLIBRARIES` is the only sensible place for them to go.